# Magento 2.3.5 Advanced Reporting access issue

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.5-p1, advanced-reporting

Our Magento advanced reporting was working fine but recently we cannot access into it!

Kindly check below image:

[image]

Advanced reporting has been enabled for years and it was working:

[image]

**The "magento analytics user" integration token is successfully re-authorized and had full access API!**

As I checked with below troubleshooting documentation:

https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-knowledge-base/kb/troubleshooting/miscellaneous/magento-advanced-reporting-troubleshooter.html

Up to step 7 (cron_schedule table) everything is checked and fixed.

But in cron_schedule, there is no record for **"analytics_collect_data"** also in Step 8, there are no **var/log/support_report.log & var/log/support_report.log.1.gz** files!

**I can't find any access.log file in var folder too!**

I have "data.tgz" file in pub/media/analytics/[hash folder]. **I have two hash  folders with two data.tgz in each!**

**Also in tmp folder there is no "analytics/tmp" folders**

I've searched a lot, but I cannot wrap my head around that why no report log is there, no record for reporting collect data in cron table!

**The last thing, the cron jobs is UP AND RUNNING .**

Please help if you had this issue and solved it somehow.
Thanks